# Error de Indentacion en python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa en tkinter que ""Encripta"" texto usando rot-13 y el modulo codecs

pero me da un error en indentacion y no se porque

(solo acepto el arreglo de la indentacion, no codigo que sea mas eficiente o facil)

este es mi codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
import codecs

def aceptar():
    try:
        n = str(var_texto.get())  # Obtenemos el número de la StringVar
    except ValueError:            # Si lo ingresado no es un entero
        var_lbl.set(f"No escogiste un número válido")
    else:                         # Si lo ingresado es un entero
        x = codecs.encode(n, 'rot_13')
        var_lbl.set(f"El codigo codificado es {n}")


root = tk.Tk()

var_texto = tk.StringVar()
var_lbl = tk.StringVar()

mi_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var_lbl)
var_lbl.set("pon el texto a codificar") # Contenido inicial del Label
mi_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

cuadro_texto = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var_texto)
cuadro_texto.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

btn_aceptar = tk.Button(root, text="Aceptar", command=aceptar)
btn_aceptar.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

este es el error que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que indentaste la linea `x = codecs.encode(n, 'rot_13')` con espacios y tenían que ser tabuladores o al revés

Comment: siiii ya me di cuenta, no sabia que habia diferente indentacion con espacios y tabuladores!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta @abrahamhs , hay que tener cuidado con las identaciones en python, ya que no es lo mismo identar con 4 espacios (o los que sean) a con `tab`.

Prueba identar todo de la misma manera. Del mismo modo, te recomiendo echarle un ojo a [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), documentacion oficial de python.